# Let $f(x)= 2x^3 +Ax^2 +4x -5$; find $A$ given $f(2) =5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let
>   $$f(x)= 2x^3 +Ax^2 +4x -5$$
>   Find $A$ given $f(2) =5$.

If I could have someone show me how to solve this it would be great

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: The solution is very straightforward. Since we know that $f(2) = 5$, then *obviously*, $$f(2) = 2(2)^3 + A(2)^2 + 4(2) - 5 = 5$$ $$\implies 16 + 4A + 8 - 5 = 5$$ $$A = \cdots?$$

Comment: Ohhhh so A=-7/2